# Need to create custom map based the spatial Database

Tags: cartography, .net, sql-server

I need to create a custom map in .net 2008 c# webapplication based the spatial database(sqlserver 2008) without using any third party tools

For example in sqlserver 2008 i am create a map using this SQLCode

```
declare @ll geometry
set @ll= geometry:: STGeomFromText('LINESTRING (80.2341763 13.0521737, 80.2340631 13.051794, 80.2340366 13.0516397, 80.2338632 13.0508963, 80.2337334 13.0503032, 80.2336701 13.0500048, 80.2335762 13.0496237, 80.2335511 13.0495047, 80.2334451 13.0490013, 80.2332654 13.0482409, 80.2332448 13.048186, 80.233076 13.0473876, 80.2329141 13.0465558, 80.2327947 13.0459422, 80.2327233 13.0455756, 80.2326847 13.0453771, 80.2326169 13.045029, 80.2325305 13.0445849, 80.2325185 13.0445234, 80.2324469 13.0439813, 80.2324085 13.0435336, 80.2324161 13.0432134)',4326)
select @ll as Geometry
```

after this excution in sqlserver2008 its display the some image , i want same image display in .net webapplication .
Please any one help in this process

Comment: Please clarify whether you are trying to create a Map, which displays geographic features across an area, or are trying to create a spatial layer, which contains the geographic features themselves.  These are two completely different operations, and while your question says "Map", the SQL you included, says "Layer".